# Copy LDAP operational attribute value

Tags: ldap, opends

I am using OpenDS. Is it possible to setup a rule that will copy value of operational attribute to another custom attribute? So when operational attribute change, custom attribute will change also.

Comment: No, why? Some problem looking directly at the operational attribute?

Comment: Yes, third-party program can't get operational attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with a custom virtual attribute plugin. Not an easy setup with just a rule, but Java code.
OpenDJ has a plugin that does this for an operational attribute (from another operational attribute).